# No Recall metric in MLEval library in Python

Tags: python, classification, metric, automl

I am exploring different AutoML libraries in Python. Found [MLEval](https://evalml.alteryx.com/en/stable/index.html) from Alteryx.

When I try to use [this tutorial](https://evalml.alteryx.com/en/stable/demos/fraud.html), I have an interesting result. I was trying to add `recall` to my metrics, but this library does not have it.

Printing

```
evalml.objectives.utils.get_core_objective_names()
```

I get

```
['expvariance',
'maxerror',
'medianae',
'mse',
'mae',
'r2',
'root mean squared error',
'mcc multiclass',
'log loss multiclass',
'auc weighted',
'auc macro',
'auc micro',
'precision weighted',
'precision macro',
'precision micro',
'f1 weighted',
'f1 macro',
'f1 micro',
'balanced accuracy multiclass',
'accuracy multiclass',
'mcc binary',
'log loss binary',
'auc',
'precision',
'f1',
'balanced accuracy binary',
'accuracy binary']
```

Did not find anything relevant so far, curious.